# JFrame window with sub components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jcomponent

So I have created this `JFrame` window which has a lot of items like `JLabel`, `JComboBox` `JTextField` etc… At the bottom it has a "next" `JButton`.

I want that when a user clicks the next button, everything on the screen should be removed and replaced with stuffs from other class that I have created.

I only manage to open a new `JFrame` window whenever I click the next button. Can somebody please tell me how to remove all items from the screen and replace them with items from another class.

Thanks. I am a newbie so please give me the easiest way possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

You could create a base panel in the BorderLayout.SOUTH position of your JFrame that would have your navigation buttons and have a number of panels added to your main panel being managed by CardLayout.

See [Creating Wizard Dialogs with Java Swing](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/swing/wizard/)

Answer (score -2):

While the systematic thing for it is using CardLayout, you can imitate it if you don't want to learn how to use it!!
Create a Panel, add all items except the next button to this panel. Use BorderLayout to put the panel on top of the next button in the frame.
Now when the user press the next button you remove the panel (jframe.remove(panel)). create a new JPanel and add it using the BorderLayout again on top of the next button.

Comment: Why would you want to do this and not use the tool created for it, the CardLayout?

Comment: @Ankur: Please re-read Reimeus' answer as it is truly the more helpful of the answers so far presented. If you do the kludge that Masood recommends, then you are fully responsible for making sure that you revalidate and repaint your containers whenever you swap components. You also become fully responsible for making sure that your container is sized large enough to hold all the sizes of the components added. If you instead use CardLayout, it does all of this for you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I agree the ultimate solution is CardLayout but as a newbie, someone may want to use manual solution just to not spend time to learn CardLayout or on the other way do this stuff and then learn CardLayout better and appreciate the services it provides.

Comment: thanks ppl for helping out me! Now I will learn CardLayout! Thanks for suggestions!